# Рейтинг постов и выборка за 7 или 30 дней самых популярных

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Задача:

Сделать рейтинг постов, чтоб голосовать можно были только 1 раз за 1 пост с 1 ip.

Мое решение:

```
|id        |int(11)
|post_id   |int(11)
|rating    |int(11)
|ip        |varchar(255)
|date_creat|timestamp
```

Считать рейтинг я буду через sum()

Но, как сделать сортировку по рейтингу например за последние 7 дней я не знаю, буду признателен если подскажите или пошлете в нужном направлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select post_id, sum(rating) rating from table
where date_create >= now() - interval 7 day
group by post_id
order by rating desc
```

Comment: проверял? )))

Comment: так сработает:

    where TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, date_create, now())<=7

Comment: @Gorets, проверял на типе datetime.
На timestamp тоже работает. В чем проблема то?
Столбец не так обозвал - date_create. Ну, так грамоте, видимо, обучен. :-)

Comment: @msi спасибо, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(RATING) FROM RATING_TABLE WHERE СЕГОДНЯ МИНУС 7 ИЛИ 30 ДНЕЙ < CREATE_DATE GROUP BY DATE_CREATE
```

Comment: нет, мне нужны самые популярные за последние 7 дней, а тут как я понял сумма рейтинга всех постов за 7 или 30 дней

Comment: без понятия что тут, проверь, я не знаю что пишу =(